# Interval calculation in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program where I need to calculate the total watch time of a movie.

```
1st watch = (0,10)
2nd Watch =(13,18)
3rd watch =(15,23)
4th watch =(21,26)
```

Total movie watched=10+5+5+3=23 min

How can I implement this in Python

Comment: Just add the numbers? I don't understand how the numbers in the "code" relate to the "10+5+5+3=23 min" by the way.

Comment: 0-10 ==10 min ,13-18==5 min, 15-23 ==5min (since the movie was already watched till 18 min in the previous interval),21-26=3 min(since earlier it was watched till 23 min)

Comment: Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question is very vague... Do you just need to total some numbers from your input?

Comment: @Luke.py the question is to identify the part of the movie that has been viewed by the user.It has to exclude the overlapped parts and calculate only the duration seen.  eg: 0-10 :the person has watched for 10 min,13-18:the person has watched for 5 min,15-23 we have to exclude till the 18th min and calculate only 18-23 as the person has already seen till the 18th min earlier

Answer (score 2):

OK, the real challenge here is with the overlapping sequences.  Sorry but your question is not very clear.

It is not optimal (see below for a better algorithm) but you can try:

```
l = [(0, 10), (13, 18), (15, 23), (21, 26)]
s = set()
for w in l:
    s = s.union(range(*w))
d = len(s)
```

It should do the trick.  It gives d = 23.

EDIT : better algorithm

```
l = [(0, 10), (13, 18), (15, 23), (21, 26)]
flat_list = sorted([(t[0], 1) for t in l] + [(t[1], -1) for t in l])
# flat_list == [(0, 1), (10, -1), (13, 1), (15, 1), (18, -1), (21, 1), (23, -1), (26, -1)]
duration = level = 0
start = None
for minute, level_inc in flat_list:
    level += level_inc
    if level == 0:
        duration += minute - start
        start = None
    elif start is None and level == 1:
        start = minute
assert(level == 0)  # something is wrong otherwise
print("Duration is {}".format(duration))
```

Comment: This works. Can you please explain the second line of the code.       flat_list = sorted([(t[0], 1) for t in l] + [(t[1], -1) for t in l]) ...what is this part doing ?

Comment: It builds a flat list containing tuples of 2 items, where the first one is the timecode and the second is 1 for a start timecode, -1 for an end timecode.  This list is sorted by timecodes.

Comment: To decompose:
`[(t[0], 1) for t in l]` is a list comprehension.  It builds a list of 2-tuples with the start timecodes.

`[(t[1], -1) for t in l]` does the same for the end timecodes, with -1 as second item instead of 1.

`[(t[0], 1) for t in l] + [(t[1], -1) for t in l]` builds a single list by appending the second list to the first one (although appending is not the right word because it is not the same object but a new one).

Then `sorted(...)` sorts this list of tuples.  The default sort for tuples is by their first item (and the next ones if needed), so in that case the timecode.

Comment: Tha makes me think that this algorithm should be verified in the case where a timecode is both a start and an end one (e.g.: 8-14, 14-17).